# I can't pass multiples parameters to a function when I use starmap

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm doing multiples experiments, but it takes a lot of time doing each one of them, so I tried to use the package `multiprocessing`, but I have an error.

The function is defined like this:

```py
def run_exp_anxia_sim(num_exp,num1,num2, 
                      eps, isfuzzy, remove, using_train, iscompress):
    if using_train == False:
        results,x , y,dic1,dic2 = classificator_pos_neg(all_pos, all_neg, test_anxia,
                                                        num_feat1=num1,num_feat2=num2,
                                                        tau=eps,fuzzy=isfuzzy,remove_stop=remove,
                                                        train_data =using_train,compress = iscompress)
        result_name = 'result_anxia_key' + str(num_exp) + '.txt'
        path_name =  '/content/sample_data'+ '/' + result_name
        
        with open(path_name, "w") as f:
            f.write("Experimento de anorexia número: " + str(num_exp) + '\n')
            f.write("Confusion matrix: \n")
            f.write(str(confusion_matrix(test_labels_anxia, results)) + '\n')

            f.write('Metrics classification \n')
            f.write(str(metrics.classification_report(test_labels_anxia, results)) + '\n')

            f.close()
        return f1_score(test_labels_anxia, results)
        
    if using_train == True:
        seed_val = 42
        np.random.seed(seed_val)
        parameters = {'C': [.05, .12, .25, .5, 1, 2, 4]}
        
        results, x, y,z,dic1,dic2 = classificator_pos_neg(all_pos, all_neg, test_anxia,num1,num2, 
                    tau=eps,fuzzy = isfuzzy,remove_stop=remove, train_data =using_train,compress = iscompress)

        svr = svm.LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced', dual=False)
        grid_anorexia = GridSearchCV(estimator=svr, param_grid=parameters, n_jobs=8, scoring='f1_macro', cv=5)
        grid_anorexia.fit(z, tr_labels)

        y_pred = grid_anorexia.predict(results)
        a1 = grid_anorexia.best_params_

        p, r, f, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(test_labels_anxia, y_pred, average='macro', pos_label=1)
        result_name = 'result_anxia_key' + str(num_exp) + '.txt'
        path_name = '/content/sample_data' + '/' + result_name
        
        
        with open(path_name, "w") as f:
            f.write("Experimento de anorexia número: " + str(num_exp) + '\n')
            f.write("Confusion matrix: \n")
            f.write(str(confusion_matrix(test_labels_anxia, y_pred)) + '\n')

            f.write('Metrics classification \n')
            f.write(str(metrics.classification_report(test_labels_anxia, y_pred)) + '\n')

            f.write('Best parameter:\n')
            f.write(str(a1))
            f.write('\n')
            f.close()
        
        return f1_score(test_labels_anxia, y_pred), a1
```

and the arguments are:

```
arg1 = [1,2]
arg6 = [1000,1500]
arg7 = [1000,1500]
arg8 = [0.99]*2
arg10 = [True]*2
arg11 = [False]*2
arg12 = [False]*2
arg13 = [False]*2
```

but when I run

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
    x,y,z,w,t = pool.apply(run_exp_anxia_sim, zip(arg1,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg10,arg11,arg12,arg13))
print(x,y,z,w,t)
```

it says

```
TypeError: run_exp_anxia_sim() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'num2', 'eps', 'isfuzzy', 'remove', 'using_train', and 'iscompress'
```

and when I try the same with `starmap` I get an error about unpacked values.

What can I do?

Comment: why are you `zip`pping the arguments? just remove `zip()` part

Comment: Your question is about `starmap`, but you're calling `pool.apply`.  You should be calling `pool.starmap` as expected.  This will call your function twice with the first element of each of the args, and then the second element of each of the args.  And yes, you want the `zip`.

Comment: I tried both because i was looking in question on this website, for starmap i got an error too:  'not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 3) '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two different things.

Firstly, `pool.apply` is limited in it's usefulness because it blocks until the result is ready, which is *probably* not something you want when using multiprocessing.

Secondly, when using `pool.apply`, the arguments you supply are directly unpacked to the target function. So because zipping creates an iterable of tuples, you will be passing that entire iterable as the first argument, which is why the error is raised since the function only got one argument.

Here is how to use `pool.apply` in this context:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def run_exp_anxia_sim(num_exp,num1,num2,
                  eps, isfuzzy, remove, using_train, iscompress):
    print(locals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg1 = [1, 2]
    arg6 = [1000, 1500]
    arg7 = [1000, 1500]
    arg8 = [0.99] * 2
    arg10 = [True] * 2
    arg11 = [False] * 2
    arg12 = [False] * 2
    arg13 = [False] * 2

    all_args = zip(arg1, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13)
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        results = [pool.apply(run_exp_anxia_sim, args=args) for args in all_args]
    print(results)
```

Here is how to instead use `pool.starmap` (which makes more sense here):

```
all_args = zip(arg1, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13)
with Pool(4) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(run_exp_anxia_sim, all_args)
print(results)
```